# Cannot connect to wifi hotspot while vpn is turned on

Tags: linux, wifi, firewall, ufw, wifi-hotspot

I am using warp-cli (cloudflare vpn) and after I enable the vpn, I cannot connect any new devices to the wifi-hotspot. Existing connected devices stay connected while vpn is turned on but no new devices can connect. Disconnecting the VPN restores the ability to connect new devices to the hotspot.

Is there any way to bypass this by creating any rule in ufw or something similar. I am not able to find any profile to allow warp-cli or cloudflare vpn in ufw.

I have the below rule created in ufw but still it doesn't allows to connect devices while vpn is turned on:

```
$ sudo ufw status

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere on wlo1           ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Anywhere (v6) on wlo1      ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

Anywhere on enp2s0         ALLOW FWD   Anywhere                  
Anywhere (v6) on enp2s0    ALLOW FWD   Anywhere (v6)
```

I had this problem in every linux disto I used (Ubuntu 16.04/18.04/20.04/20.10/22.04/22.10, openSUSE, Mint, Arch, RHEL, etc) have this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

By the description you give I assume you're creating a hotspot on a Linux system, and the aim is to protect the connected Wi-Fi client internet connection with the VPN.

1. Ensure your VPN is only running on the interface connected to the internet, not on your Wi-Fi interface
2. Whitelist the local network on the Linux box VPN client

An alternative is to install the VPN client on each Wi-Fi client separately.

Comment: The VPN is running globaly i.e running on the entire system and how can I run VPN only for specific interface and even if it runs then also how it can accept new connection from another interface to run in the same subnet. 

I need to separate every interface and the system so that VPN can run only forr the system and not  on the interface.

Comment: If I misunderstood your goal, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/742412/edit) your question to clarify what exactly you want to achieve. Please remember that nobody knows about your setup or aim anything else but what you specifically tell. The more details you give the better answers you can expect. Please include all the relevant configuration files, commands, error messages etc. enclosed in the code brackets `{ }` on the edit box toolbar. Please also explain which interface connects to the internet, which is supposed to serve the local network.

Comment: _"how it can accept new connection from another interface to run in the same subnet"_ - basically it can't, or at least it requires a great deal of difficulty. There are usually easy ways to do things, but without knowing your exact goal, configs etc. it's not possible to determine where things go wrong and how the situation can be remedied.